# How to Read a text file using Java script and display it in column fashion in HTML.?

Tags: html, jscript

## This is the code which reads the text file using the Jscript and displays it in HTML. But i need it to display it in table.

**How to display it in Table.**
< this is my first question so i hope i get solution >

`
    
      
         Read File (via User Input selection)
        
        var reader; //GLOBAL File Reader object for demo purpose only

```
    /**
     * Check for the various File API support.
     */
    function checkFileAPI() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            return true; 
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * read text input
     */
    function readText(filePath) {
        var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
        if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {           
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                output = e.target.result;
                displayContents(output);
            };//end onload()
            reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
        }//end if html5 filelist support
        else if(ActiveXObject && filePath) { //fallback to IE 6-8 support via ActiveX
            try {
                reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
                output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
                file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
                displayContents(output);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.number == -2146827859) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files due to browser security settings. ' + 
                     'To overcome this, go to Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level. ' + 
                     'Find the setting for "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" and change it to "Enable" or "Prompt"'); 
                }
            }       
        }
        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
            return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }   

    /**
     * display content using a basic HTML replacement
     */
    function displayContents(txt) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
        el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkFileAPI();">
    <div id="container">    
        <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
        <br/>
        <hr/>   
        <h3>Contents of the Text file:</h3>
        <div id="main">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Please help me in this

Comment: What kind of text is there in the text file? Can it be read as tabular data? Or do you just want the entire text within one table cell?

Comment: Ya it can be read as a tabular Data.

Comment: Actually Entire text file contact 3 tables i have to display it in html front end.

Comment: How are the rows, columns and tables separated in the text file? Can you give an example? The solution would be to split the tables, rows and columns from the text file and wrap them in their corresponding HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the text file like a SSV (TSV or CSV as well), then instead of `ReadAll()` I'd do something like this:

```
var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1),
    data = [], n;
while (!file.AtEndOfStream) {
    data.push(file.ReadLine().split(';')); // or use some other "cell-separator"
}
```

Then the rest is a lot simpler and faster, if you've an empty `table` element in your HTML:

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

Now just create rows and cells dynamically based on the `data` array:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    len = data.length,
    r, row, c, cell;
for (r = 0; r < len; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (c = 0; c < data[r].lenght; r++) {
        cell.row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = data[r][c];
    }
}
```